# need pandas tabular / pivot result with two df

Tags: python, pandas

we have two df

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['a','b','c','a1','b1','c1','a2','b2','c2','a3','b3','c3'], 
    'b':[1,2,3,11,21,31,12,22,32,13,23,33]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'S':[200], 'M':[300],'L':[200], 'XL':[300],'2XL':[200], '3XL':[300]})
```

need result like as pivot table

```
Item Qty   S     M      L       XL    2XL    3Xl    total
a     200 200*1  300*1  200*1  300*1  200*1  300*1   1500
b     300 200*2
c     400 200*3
a1    200
b1    100
c1    400
a2    100
b2    104
c2    402
a3    150
b3    140
c3    170

total  ???   ???
```

now we need this type of result like as pivot or tabular

Comment: ITEM QTY S M L XL 2XL 3XL TOTAL 
A 3 200 300 200 300 200 300 1500
S 5       
D 6       
F 2       
J 7       
K 0.99       
L 0.25       
GH 0.45       
H 0.55       
GFH 4       
        
TOTAL   200      1500
SIR NEED THIS TYPE RESULT

Answer (score 1):

You can multiple values of `df1['b']` with first row of `df2` with broadcasting and add `Item` and `total` columns:

```
out = (df1.join(pd.DataFrame(df1['b'].to_numpy()[:, None] * df2.iloc[0].to_numpy(), 
                    columns=df2.columns, index=df1.index)
          .assign(total = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)))
          .rename(columns={'b':'Qty'}))

print (out)
   Item  Qty     S     M     L    XL   2XL   3XL  total
0     a    1   200   300   200   300   200   300   1500
1     b    2   400   600   400   600   400   600   3000
2     c    3   600   900   600   900   600   900   4500
3    a1   11  2200  3300  2200  3300  2200  3300  16500
4    b1   21  4200  6300  4200  6300  4200  6300  31500
5    c1   31  6200  9300  6200  9300  6200  9300  46500
6    a2   12  2400  3600  2400  3600  2400  3600  18000
7    b2   22  4400  6600  4400  6600  4400  6600  33000
8    c2   32  6400  9600  6400  9600  6400  9600  48000
9    a3   13  2600  3900  2600  3900  2600  3900  19500
10   b3   23  4600  6900  4600  6900  4600  6900  34500
11   c3   33  6600  9900  6600  9900  6600  9900  49500
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'a3', 'b3', 'c3'],
                    'Qty': [1, 2, 3, 11, 21, 31, 12, 22, 32, 13, 23, 33]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'S': [200], 'M': [300], 'L': [200], 'XL': [300], '2XL': [200], '3XL': [300]})

# Merge the two dataframes on the 'Item' column
result_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Item', right_index=True)

# Multiply the 'Qty' column by each size column
for size in ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', '2XL', '3XL']:
    result_df[size] = result_df['Qty'] * result_df[size]

# Sum the values for each size
result_df_sum = result_df.groupby('Item')[['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', '2XL', '3XL']].sum().reset_index()

# Calculate the 'total' column
result_df_sum['total'] = result_df_sum[['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', '2XL', '3XL']].sum(axis=1)

print(result_df_sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.outer`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['a','b','c','a1','b1','c1','a2','b2','c2','a3','b3','c3'], 
    'b':[1,2,3,11,21,31,12,22,32,13,23,33]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'S':[200], 'M':[300],'L':[200], 'XL':[300],'2XL':[200], '3XL':[300]})

q = df1.set_index('Item').to_numpy()
s = df2.to_numpy()
df_out = ((df_m:=pd.DataFrame(np.outer(q, s), index=df1['Item'], columns=df2.columns))
           .assign(total=df_m.sum(1), Qty=df1['b'].to_numpy()))

df_out.loc['total', :] = df_out.sum()
df_out = df_out.astype('int')

df_out
```

Output:

```
           S      M      L     XL    2XL    3XL   total  Qty
Item                                                        
a        200    300    200    300    200    300    1500    1
b        400    600    400    600    400    600    3000    2
c        600    900    600    900    600    900    4500    3
a1      2200   3300   2200   3300   2200   3300   16500   11
b1      4200   6300   4200   6300   4200   6300   31500   21
c1      6200   9300   6200   9300   6200   9300   46500   31
a2      2400   3600   2400   3600   2400   3600   18000   12
b2      4400   6600   4400   6600   4400   6600   33000   22
c2      6400   9600   6400   9600   6400   9600   48000   32
a3      2600   3900   2600   3900   2600   3900   19500   13
b3      4600   6900   4600   6900   4600   6900   34500   23
c3      6600   9900   6600   9900   6600   9900   49500   33
total  40800  61200  40800  61200  40800  61200  306000  204
```